# Drag value using 2 different array with python (simil flip flop)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'd like to obtain a new array (named Result) from 2 different arrays where:

```
0 _ 0 => Hold state
1 _ 0 => 1
0 _ 1 => 0
1 _ 1 => 0
```

Example:

```
array1  array2  Result
     0       0       0
     0       1       0
     1       1       0
     1       0       1
     0       0       1
     0       0       1
     1       0       1
     0       0       1
     1       1       0
     0       0       0
     0       1       0
     0       0       0
     1       0       1
     0       0       1
```

it is like
[Latch SR Flip Flop device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#SR_NOR_latch) The only difference is `1 1 => 0`

I'd like to use pandas or numpy. Thank you for your help.  I wrote this one and it works but it's too much slow.

```
def FLIP(array1, array2):

    assert array1.index.equals(array2.index), 'Indices do not match'
    array = pd.Series(False, dtype=bool, index=array1.index)
    i = 0
    while i < len(array1):
        if array1[i]:
            array[i] = True
            for j in xrange(i, len(array2)):
                if array2[j]:
                    array[j] = False
                    break
                array[j] = True
            i = j
        i += 1
    return array.fillna(value=False)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this you'll have to explain the process of how you arrive at the result

Comment: it is like Latch SR Flip Flop device
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#SR_NOR_latch <\br>
    The only difference is 1 1 => 0 <\br>
    I'd like to use pandas or numpy.

Comment: I'd like to obtain a new array (named Result) from 2 different arrays where:

- 0 _ 0 => Hold state
- 1 _ 0 => 1
- 0 _ 1 => 0
- 1 _ 1 => 0

Comment: I've changed the code, missing one line.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding correctly, we can take advantage of how `pandas` treats `nan` to handle the "hold" logic:

```
def flipper(a1, a2):
    res = pd.Series(index=a1.index) 
    res.loc[a1 == 1] = 1
    res.loc[a2 == 1] = 0
    res = res.ffill().fillna(0)
    return res
```

This gives the expected result in your test case:

```
>>> df
    array1  array2  Result  result_computed
0        0       0       0                0
1        0       1       0                0
2        1       1       0                0
3        1       0       1                1
4        0       0       1                1
5        0       0       1                1
6        1       0       1                1
7        0       0       1                1
8        0       1       0                0
9        0       0       0                0
10       0       1       0                0
11       0       0       0                0
12       1       0       1                1
13       0       0       1                1
```

And seems to match your output in general:

```
from itertools import product

def check():
    for w in range(1, 9):
        for a0 in product(range(2), repeat=w):
            for a1 in product(range(2), repeat=w):
                s0, s1 = pd.Series(a0), pd.Series(a1)
                flipper_result = flipper(s0, s1)
                FLIP_result = FLIP(s0, s1)
                assert (flipper_result == FLIP_result).all()
    return True

>>> check()
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas forward filling functions to avoid a python loop over your data.

Other than the "hold state" part, the rest is basically a bitwise shift.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

array1 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
array2 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

expected = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

def flip(series1, series2):
    series1, series2 = pd.Series(series1), pd.Series(series2)

    out = pd.Series(np.nan, series1.index)
    out[:] = (series1 >> series2).astype(int)
    out[(series1 == 0) & (series2 == 0)] = np.nan
    return out.ffill()

print flip(array1, array2).values
print expected
```

Note that this leaves the starting value undefined. If you'd prefer you can fill it with whatever value makes sense (e.g. 0).

Comment: @ARpython - For what it's worth, DSM's answer is a bit more efficient than mine.  They're both the same basic idea, though.

Comment: @Joe: not only are they the same basic idea, I almost didn't hit post when I saw you'd done the same thing (ffill) a minute earlier. :-)

Comment: @DSM - I almost deleted mine when I saw yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [DataFrame.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). This appears much faster than the provided method. On an array of 10,000 elements, it's about 50 times faster. On a 10^6 array, it took 220ms.

```
In [80]: data = pd.DataFrame({
   ....:     'array1': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   ....:     'array2': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   ....: })

In [81]: flipflop = pd.DataFrame({
   ....:     'array1': [0, 1, 0, 1],
   ....:     'array2': [0, 0, 1, 1],
   ....:     'Result': [pd.np.nan, 1, 0, 0]
   ....: })

In [82]: data.merge(flipflop, how='left', on=['array1', 'array2']).ffill().fillna(0)
Out[82]:
    array1  array2  Result
0        0       0       0
1        0       1       0
2        1       1       0
3        1       0       1
4        0       0       1
5        0       0       1
6        1       0       1
7        0       0       1
8        0       1       0
9        0       0       0
10       0       1       0
11       0       0       0
12       1       0       1
13       0       0       1

In [83]: data = pd.DataFrame({
   ....:     'array1': pd.np.random.random_integers(0, 1, 10000),
   ....:     'array2': pd.np.random.random_integers(0, 1, 10000),
   ....: })

In [84]: %timeit FLIP(data.array1, data.array2)
10 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop

In [85]: %timeit data.merge(flipflop, how='left', on=['array1', 'array2']).ffill().fillna(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.97 ms per loop
```

Comment: Incredible.

This community is wonderful.

Again, many thanks to you all

Answer (score 0):

The result you're looking for is history-dependent so I'm not aware of much scope for avoiding a loop over the two arrays.

```
def flip(array1, array2):

    currentstate = 0
    result = []

    for i, j in zip(array1, array2):

        if (i < j):

            currentstate = 0

        if (j < i):

            currentstate = 1

        result.append(currentstate)

    return np.array(result)
```

Comment: I won't use For because I have a dataframe of 10^6 rows and it's too slow.